# Is Google Chart Tool Api is free to use

Tags: java, charts, google-visualization

Is Google Chart API free to use? If so, where can I find its documentation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal advice question.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Yes, it is free. It is written in the [official page](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/):

> Completely free for all uses:
>   commercial, governmental, personal or
>   educational.

For documentation follow this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/).

Edit:
You don't really download it. You include the following in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Then you start using it as shown [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start.html).

If you really want to see how it looks like inside, you can paste this to your browser address bar: http://www.google.com/jsapi

Comment: Welcome to SO, I +1 your answer as you have provided a clearer answer.

Comment: could you please tell me where to find api libraries to download

Comment: @user571616 if you find  that a question has been correctly answered, "accepting" it is a good way to say "thanks" to the user who did it.

Comment: There are no libraries to download - the intention is to reference google's javascript API from your web page and use that. http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start.html and http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/faq.html#creatingaclient

Comment: thanks @ktulinho, but I also need the link of the api to download, is it possible to use it offline

Comment: @user571616 Then you need to probably follow the thing written in the last paragraph :)

Answer (score 6):

its completely free. You can check the different chart from below link

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization